# Libtool: link one of the project generated libs statically

Tags: makefile, build, static-linking, autotools, libtool

I have a project that builds with

```
autoreconf --install
./configure
make
```

and contains `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am`
The project builds 2 libraries and one executable that dynamically links them. One library is cpp, other and the executable are pure C. I want to link one of the libs (cpp one) statically and keep c library to link dynamically. My simplified `Makefile.am` is

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

SUBDIRS = include doc po

AM_CPPFLAGS = -Iinclude
AM_CPPFLAGS += -D__STRICT_ANSI__
AM_CPPFLAGS += -DNDEBUG

WARNFLAGS = -Wall

AM_CFLAGS = $(WARNFLAGS) $(OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) -std=c11
AM_CXXFLAGS = $(WARNFLAGS) -std=c++11

localedir = $(datadir)/locale
DEFS = -DLOCALEDIR=\"$(localedir)\" @DEFS@

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmy.la libmy-settings.la

libmy_la_SOURCES = src/sharedlib.c src/sharedlib.h

libmy_settings_la_SOURCES = src/staticlib.cpp src/staticlib.h

bin_PROGRAMS = myapp

myapp_SOURCES = myapp.c

myapp_LDADD = libmy.la libmy-settings.la
```

The libtool generates both `.a` and `.so` files in `./.libs/` but Libtool prefers `.so`. In the last `make` command I see `gcc -Wall -std=c11 -g -O2 -o .libs/myapp myapp.o  ./.libs/libmy.so ./.libs/libmy-settings.so`. If I replace it with `gcc -Wall -std=c11 -g -O2 -o .libs/myapp myapp.o  ./.libs/libmy.so ./.libs/libmy-settings.a` - it works and gives me that I'm trying to achieve. The question is: how to achieve it automatically wit help of `Makefile.am`?

As I understand, I can't just add `myapp_LDFLAGS=-lmy-settings.a` bcs it won't replace shared linking argument but add a new one. And I can't remove the `libmy-settings.la` from `lib_LTLIBRARIES` or `myapp_LDADD` bcs it won't generate libmy-settings.a or libmysettings.so in ./.libs/ at all.  Any clues?

Comment: Do you need to have `libmy-settings` as a separately installable library at all?  That is, are you trying to provide for other programs to be able to link it, too?

Comment: The `libmy.so` is a separately installable library. The `libmy-settings` are the code that i contribute to the project and i would like to make it statically linked lib and not installable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `libmy-settings` does not need to be a separately installable library, you have two pretty straightfoward alternatives:

1. Add its sources to `myapp_SOURCES`, and leave `libmy-settings.la` completely out of the picture.  That the additional sources are located in a different directory and written in a different (autotools-supported) language should not be a problem.  This approach may be to your advantage in terms of the Autotools choosing the correct linker driver and options without your intervention, too.
2. Build `libmy-settings.la` as a utility library instead of an installable one.  This is achieved by marking it `noinst`:

   ```
   lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmy.la
   noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libmy-settings.la
   ```